# Find next cell within column that is a number, starting from reference cell in another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I think this sounds simple but I'm having a bit of trouble figuring it out.

I have 2 sheets, the Sample Sheet attached and an Input Sheet.
In the Input Sheet, I input one of the green shaded values (10001, 10002, 10003) in a cell, say A2. Is there a way to match A2 in Sample!A:A and move down along the column until I hit the first number (3, 4, 3)?

For example, if A2 is filled with 10002, I need the formula in another cell to return A14, or 4.

My end goal is to actually get to the corresponding yellow shaded cell, and I was thinking I could just offset after hitting the first number from the reference cell.
I hope that makes sense!

[Sample Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnQ74.jpg)

Comment: You have included tags for `[google-spreadsheets]` and `[microsoft-excel]` which is it?

Comment: And what are you planning to do with the number in the yellow shaded cell? This may be an XY problem. Assuming you always have a cell containing "Store:" you could use `=ROW()+MATCH("Store:",A2:A200,0)-2` to get the desired row

Comment: Sorry about that Blind Spots, I had trouble finding relevant tags that the site allowed me to post. It's Google Sheets

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad , I just need to return the value in the yellow shaded cell into another sheet. I would have to return just a specific yellow shaded cell depending on the referenced range. To clarify, the green shaded cells are actually a mix of a date and a code. In the actual data set (which I am not allowed to edit the format of), there could be hundreds of these ranges

Comment: I updated [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/1772898 "link to answer") as I did not realize it was the value in column E to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### Formula

- The formula returns the value in column E of the first row that follows a specified lookup value and also contains a number in column A.
- Formula is in a single sheet for simplicity but can be easily adapted to a separate sheet.
- Formula will work in MS Excel and Google Sheets (links to support articles are for Google sheets.

```
=INDEX(FILTER(A:E,
    (ISNUMBER(A:A)*(ROW(A:A)>MATCH(H3,A:A,0)))),
    1,5)
```

##### How the Formula was assembled

1. [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) is applied to the range `A:E` using [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296) to include only rows with numbers in column A: `FILTER(A:E, ISNUMBER(A:A))`
2. [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) is used to return the row number of cell `H3` (the lookup value): `MATCH(H3,A:A,0)`
3. Using [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316) and the previous [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378), an additional condition `(ROW(A:A)>MATCH(H3,A:A,0))` is added to the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) to include only rows located below `>` the lookup value's row:
   `=FILTER(AE:A,(ISNUMBER(A:A)*(ROW(A:A)>MATCH(H3,A:A,0))))`
4. It remains only to use [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) to return the value in the 1st row and the 5th column of the filtered array: `INDEX(array,1,5)`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Blind Spots! I adjusted the formula for use with the actual sheets and it worked perfectly. And the explanations are also so clear that I feel I can better apply the individual functions elsewhere. I keep forgetting about the Filter function and kept trying to force an index/match/offset formula. Again, thank you for your time, really needed this!